# Website for sharing solutions/proof verification?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, self-learning

Is there a website for sharing solutions to exercises in math books? I'm self-studying math and I find solution manuals [like this](http://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/) very helpful. When I do an exercise, I usually scribble down a few lines (sometimes I don't write anything at all), then look at the solution and if I see the same idea as mine, I'm convinced that my proof is correct or at least I got the right idea. If my proof is different from proof given in the solution manual, I write it down in great detail to verify that it's correct. This takes a lot of time.

Unfortunately, few books have solution manuals. For example, "A Course in Algebra" by E. B. Vinberg is a very popular book in my country, but there is no solution manual. It's a pity that a lot of people do exercises from this book every year and their solutions just go to a trash can.

Solution manuals save a lot of time and provide some degree of comfort. It'd be nice to have a website with search by title and author, where people would post their $\LaTeX$-formatted solutions to each exercise and vote for best solutions. My question is whether such a website exists and if it doesn't, why? Is there any legal or pedagogical reasons?

Comment: First of all, there are a lot of math courses and for each course, there are a lot of books that one can choose. Now once you've fixed a course and a book, there are now lots of partial solutions manuals, written by a multitude of authors ranging from the original author, other professors, grad students, and even other students. Undertaking such a task on more than a book by book basis would be quite daunting, not to mention probably not that useful given that Google exists.